# Combine Multiple Related Functions into For Loop with last Index

Tags: python, loops, indexing

I am having a bit of trouble combining multiple functions in a for loop. Essentially, I want to create a list of points defined by a quadratic equation Y = (A/2)x^2 + Bx + C where A, B and C are constants. For the first loop B and C are zero so my function might look something like this:

[image]

I want to grab the slope (M) of this plot at the last index and pass that into a linear equation (dy/dx = Mx + B) where B is the offset from the first plot (Y value at last index):

[image]

I then want to plot the first quadratic equation again with a starting C value as the dy/dx value at last index from the linear function (Y = (A/2)x^2 + Bx + C). So on and so fourth until I have strung together a bunch of quadratic and linear equations in a row. I am hoping for something like this where each quadratic section is of the same length along x and each linear section is also the same length along x and constant data is obtained from the previous plot.

[image]

I tried to generate this code with for loops but was unsure how to combine them in a way that iterates over several different "channels". I was unsure how to grab the final index of one loop that is nested inside of another. Code of my initial attempt below (does not iterate through channels).

```
# Define Channels
channels = list(range(1,17))
V = np.random.randint(0,16,16)
# Define Positional Increments
c = 1 #constant
Ch_Len = 1 #mm
Gap_Len = 1 #mm
Inc = 10 # Increment Scale (um)
#
CT = len(channels) #total channels
CL = Ch_Len*Inc #steps for each channel
GL = Gap_Len*Inc #steps for each gap
#
CH = []
GP = []
K1 = [0]
K2 = [0]
#
# Calculate Channel 1 with V[0]
i = 0;
for j in range(CL):
    CH_Eq = ((0.5)*c*V[i]*(j**2) + K1[i]*j + K2[0]) # V'', Starting with K=0
    CH.append(CH_Eq)
K1.append(CH[CL-1])
#
# Calculate Gap 1 with V[0]
G1 = []
SlopeC1 = c*V[i]*K1[1];
for m in range(GL):
    G_Eq = SlopeC1*m + K1[1]
    G1.append(G_Eq)
K2.append(G1[GL-1])
```

I am unsure how to make this one big loop. Or maybe there is a better way to go about writing this code. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just wrap the two loops in one big outer for-loop over `i` and adjust some indices (if `CH` is a list, `CH[-1]` is the last item in it).